# Fourier transform integral

Tags: integral-transforms

I'm trying to calculate the 3D fourier transform of this function:

$$\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}}$$

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Possible DUplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55419/2-dimensional-fourier-transform-integral

Comment: @DJC Not an exact duplicate, as the question you linked to has $3/2$ in the denominator rather than $1/2$, but similar solution methods will probably work

Comment: Hi, if a similar method would work, how would you implement it? The method used before was 2D (it relied on using cylindrical bessel functions) and I was unable to adapt it to this question.

Comment: The downvoter should perhaps explain the reason for the downvote.

Comment: Have you tried spherical coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

Inserting the Jacobian $r^2\sin\theta$
and $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=r$ in polar coordinates gives

\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty r^2 dr \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \int_0^\pi \sin\theta d\theta \frac{1}{r} e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{r}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
=
\int_0^\infty r^2 dr \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \int_0^\pi \sin\theta d\theta \frac{1}{r} e^{ikr\cos\theta}
\end{equation}

and with $z=\cos\theta$, $dz=-\sin\theta d\theta$
\begin{equation}
=
2\pi \int_0^\infty r dr \int_0^\pi \sin\theta d\theta e^{ikr\cos\theta}
=
-2\pi \int_0^\infty r dr \int_{1}^{-1} dz e^{ikrz}
=
2\pi \int_0^\infty r dr \int_{-1}^{1} dz e^{ikrz}
\end{equation}
and with $t=ikrz$, $dz=dt/(ikr)$
\begin{equation}
=
2\pi \int_0^\infty r dr \frac{1}{ikr} \int_{-ikr}^{ikr} dt e^t
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=
2\pi \int_0^\infty r dr \frac{1}{ikr} [e^{ikr}-e^{-ikr}]
=
4\pi \int_0^\infty r dr \frac{1}{kr} \sin(kr)
=
\frac{4\pi}{k^2} \int_0^\infty kr d(kr) \frac{1}{kr} \sin(kr)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=
\frac{4\pi}{k^2} \int_0^\infty d(kr) \sin(kr)
=
\frac{4\pi}{k^2} \int_0^\infty dz \sin z
\end{equation}
and this exists only in the theory of distributions.

Comment: For OP: Heuristically, $\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin z \, dz = 1$ and hence the Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{|x|}$ is $\frac{4\pi}{|\xi|^{2}}$. Of course, this is justified in distribution sense.

Comment: For some rigorous treatment, one can refer to Proposition 4.1 of [*Lectures on Harmonic Analysis*](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~ilaba/wolff/notes_march2002.pdf) by Thomas H. Wolff.